# Mangled UTM campaign name

Tags: email, analytics, sendgrid, matomo, utm

I have been sending emails with SendGrid containing links with UTM parameters.

As I test I have tried with `utm_campaign=testing%20weird%20campaign%20codes` (`testing weird campaign codes`) and I have gotten visits with `testing weird campaign codes` but also with a strange mangled version: `gffgvat jfvee dbzcbvta dbeff`. Actually, I got an order of magnitude more visits with the mangled campaign code.

The spacing and word lengths are preserved, but it is not a straightforward replacement cipher as far as I can tell. It is unclear to me if it is intentional obfuscation, encryption or some encoding glitch.

I got these UTMs both with Matomo and Microsoft Clarity, I don't think the issue is on the analytics side.

I have seen some loose references online that Microsoft's Advanced Threat Protection tends to do things like this, mangling URL parameters. Although nothing conclusive from reputable sources.